# Defining Property Chains in rdflib with owl.propertyChainAxiom

Tags: rdf, owl, rdflib

I am having a lot of trouble understanding how to use property chains in RDFLib. Is there a way to do this without a SPARQL Insert statement instead using `Graph.add(())`?

For instance, the below won't work, I didn't really expect it to.

```
gg.add((URIRef("http://example.org/propertyB"), owl.propertyChainAxiom, (URIRef("http://example.org/propertyB"), URIRef("http://example.org/propertyC"))))
```

Comment: `rdflib` is a framework for RDF - your property chain is a feature of OWL. There is an RDF serialiazion of OWL axioms, but this can take more than one triple in general. Indeed, `graph.add` doesn't work as it expects triples of RDF resources. If you want to add such an OWL axiom via `rdflib`, then you have to add the corresponding triples each as defined here: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/ . you can see from the specs that the property chain has as object an RDF list (the `rdf:rest` and `rdf:first` triples). In your case it means you have add **5 RDF triples** via `rdflib`